# How to atomically move rows from one table to another?

Tags: mysql, sql, atomic

I am collecting readings from several thousand sensors and storing them in a MySQL database. There are several hundred inserts per second. To improve the insert performance I am storing the values initially into a MEMORY buffer table. Once a minute I run a stored procedure which moves the inserted rows from the memory buffer to a permanent table.

Basically I would like to do the following in my stored procedure to move the rows from the temporary buffer:

```
INSERT INTO data SELECT * FROM data_buffer;
DELETE FROM data_buffer;
```

Unfortunately the previous is not usable because the data collection processes insert additional rows in "data_buffer" between INSERT and DELETE above. Thus those rows will get deleted without getting inserted to the "data" table.

How can I make the operation atomic or make the DELETE statement to delete only the rows which were SELECTed and INSERTed in the preceding statement?

I would prefer doing this in a standard way which works on different database engines if possible.

I would prefer not adding any additional "id" columns because of performance overhead and storage requirements.

I wish there was SELECT_AND_DELETE or MOVE statement in standard SQL or something similar...

Comment: Could you provide structure of data_buffer table?

Comment: Sure:
CREATE TABLE `data_buffer` (
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sensor` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `value` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: I have actually one MySQL specific solution but it appears I am not allowed to post it in the answers section before 8 hours has passed. I really hate these limits in stackoverflow...

Comment: How about having a row id, get the max value before insert, then delete records <= max(id)

Comment: @niktrs, this is a clever idea! There will be some additional overhead because of the otherwise un-needed id column but on the other hand this should be possible on any DB engine in the same way (apart from the syntax of defining the AUTO_INCREMENT column). Too bad you didn't post it in the answers section. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way to avoid all those problems, and to also stay fast, would be to use two `data_buffer` tables (let's call them `data_buffer1` and `data_buffer2`); while the collection processes insert into `data_buffer2`, you can do the `insert` and `delete` on `data_buffer2`; than you switch, so collected data goes into `data_buffer2`, while data is inserted+deleted from `data_buffer1` into `data`.

Comment: In the end I implemented a variation of this solution: the RENAME TABLE solution which I wrote about in my own answer. However because it is based on the idea in this answer, I am choosing this answer as my accepted answer. Using alternating tables is the best solution in my case because there is no extra overhead from record-keeping id columns and the inserts from sensors will not be blocked due to locking.

Answer (score 3):

I beleive this will work but will block until insert is done

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO data (SELECT * FROM data_buffer FOR UPDATE); 
DELETE FROM data_buffer; 
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Nope. "SELECT FOR UPDATE" locks only the SELECTed rows but does not prevent INSERTing new rows.

Comment: Sorry. Actually it works with MEMORY tables (if made into a single transaction) because they currently support only table level locks. I would rather not depend on current storage engine characteristics, who knows if the next version of MySQL implements row level locks for memory tables or someone decides to put the temporary table in a NDB memory table (which supports row level locks).

Comment: Yeah. Thanks! The edited revision works and does not depend on MySQL storage engine limitations. It is not perfect though because it blocks all new inserts in "data_buffer" while the procedure is running.

Comment: yeah it blocks but not entirely.. just blocks the commits so inserts are working correctly

Answer (score 1):

How about having a row id, get the max value before insert, make the insert and then delete records <= max(id)

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar solution to @ammoQ's answer. The difference is that instead of having the INSERTing process figure out which table to write to, you can transparently swap the tables in the scheduled procedure.

Use RENAME in the scheduled procedure to swap tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_buffer_new LIKE data_buffer;
RENAME TABLE data_buffer TO data_buffer_old, data_buffer_new TO data_buffer;
INSERT INTO data SELECT * FROM data_buffer_old;
DROP TABLE data_buffer_old;
```

This works because RENAME statement swaps the tables atomically, thus the INSERTing processes will not fail with "table not found". This is MySQL specific though.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the tables are identical, with the same columns and primary key(s)? If that is the case, you could nestled select inside a where clause...something like this:

```
DELETE FROM data_buffer 
WHERE primarykey IN (SELECT primarykey FROM data)
```

Comment: This would work if there was any "primarykey". Currently there isn't because it is not needed for other purposes. However I think it would be very slow because there is a **huge** amount of rows in the *data* table.

Answer (score 0):

This is a MySQL specific solution. You can use locking to prevent the INSERTing processes from adding new rows while you are moving rows.

The procedure which moves the rows should be as follows:

```
LOCK TABLE data_buffer READ;
INSERT INTO data SELECT * FROM data_buffer;
DELETE FROM data_buffer;
UNLOCK TABLE;
```

The code which INSERTs new rows in the buffer should be changed as follows:

```
LOCK TABLE data_buffer WRITE;
INSERT INTO data_buffer VALUES (1, 2, 3);
UNLOCK TABLE;
```

The INSERT process will obviously block while the lock is in place.

Comment: It appears that this solution is wrong, because it is not possible to use LOCK TABLES in stored procedures as described in (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-program-restrictions.html). Unfortunately I can not downvote my own answer. :)